# Javascript: analyze how a value gets changed on a website

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, post

As I got confronted with the [political compass](https://www.politicalcompass.org) dozens of times in politics class, I started a journey, to understand, how the official website calculates ones political position.

As looking at the source code, did really confuse me, I tried a different approach to understand what happens: I ran the test two times with different answers and copied the 6 POST-Request, which my Browser did send.

**POST-Requests from Run 1:**

```
page=1&carried_ec=&carried_soc=&populated=&globalisationinevitable=0&countryrightorwrong=0&proudofcountry=0&racequalities=0&enemyenemyfriend=0&militaryactionlaw=0&fusioninfotainment=0
page=2&carried_ec=5&carried_soc=-9&populated=&classthannationality=0&inflationoverunemployment=0&corporationstrust=0&fromeachability=0&freermarketfreerpeople=0&bottledwater=0&landcommodity=0&manipulatemoney=0&protectionismnecessary=0&companyshareholders=0&richtaxed=0&paymedical=0&penalisemislead=0&freepredatormulinational=0
page=3&carried_ec=19&carried_soc=-9&populated=&abortionillegal=0&questionauthority=0&eyeforeye=0&taxtotheatres=0&schoolscompulsory=0&ownkind=0&spankchildren=0&naturalsecrets=0&marijuanalegal=0&schooljobs=0&inheritablereproduce=0&childrendiscipline=0&savagecivilised=0&abletowork=0&represstroubles=0&immigrantsintegrated=0&goodforcorporations=0&broadcastingfunding=0
page=4&carried_ec=5&carried_soc=-34&populated=&libertyterrorism=0&onepartystate=0&serveillancewrongdoers=0&deathpenalty=0&societyheirarchy=0&abstractart=0&punishmentrehabilitation=0&wastecriminals=0&businessart=0&mothershomemakers=0&plantresources=0&peacewithestablishment=0
page=5&carried_ec=5&carried_soc=-70&populated=&astrology=0&moralreligious=0&charitysocialsecurity=0&naturallyunlucky=0&schoolreligious=0
page=6&carried_ec=0&carried_soc=-87&populated=&sexoutsidemarriage=0&homosexualadoption=0&pornography=0&consentingprivate=0&naturallyhomosexual=0&opennessaboutsex=0
```

**POST-Requests from Run 2:**

```
page=1&carried_ec=&carried_soc=&populated=&globalisationinevitable=3&countryrightorwrong=3&proudofcountry=3&racequalities=3&enemyenemyfriend=3&militaryactionlaw=3&fusioninfotainment=3
page=2&carried_ec=-4&carried_soc=9&populated=&classthannationality=3&inflationoverunemployment=3&corporationstrust=3&fromeachability=3&freermarketfreerpeople=3&bottledwater=3&landcommodity=3&manipulatemoney=3&protectionismnecessary=3&companyshareholders=3&richtaxed=3&paymedical=3&penalisemislead=3&freepredatormulinational=3
page=3&carried_ec=-17&carried_soc=9&populated=&abortionillegal=3&questionauthority=3&eyeforeye=3&taxtotheatres=3&schoolscompulsory=3&ownkind=3&spankchildren=3&naturalsecrets=3&marijuanalegal=3&schooljobs=3&inheritablereproduce=3&childrendiscipline=3&savagecivilised=3&abletowork=3&represstroubles=3&immigrantsintegrated=3&goodforcorporations=3&broadcastingfunding=3
page=4&carried_ec=-5&carried_soc=30&populated=&libertyterrorism=3&onepartystate=3&serveillancewrongdoers=3&deathpenalty=3&societyheirarchy=3&abstractart=3&punishmentrehabilitation=3&wastecriminals=3&businessart=3&mothershomemakers=3&plantresources=3&peacewithestablishment=3
page=5&carried_ec=-5&carried_soc=67&populated=&astrology=3&moralreligious=3&charitysocialsecurity=3&naturallyunlucky=3&schoolreligious=3
page=6&carried_ec=0&carried_soc=84&populated=&sexoutsidemarriage=3&homosexualadoption=3&pornography=3&consentingprivate=3&naturallyhomosexual=3&opennessaboutsex=3
```

By looking at them, I came to the conclusion, that after each part of the quiz, an *economic political position* value `carried_ec` and a *social political position* value `carried_soc` get calculated. Those get added onto the values resulting from the next part of the quiz.

In the next step, I went to the `view-source:` in my Firefox and hit `strg+f` an searched for `carried_ec` and `carried_soc`. They are only found once in the source code, under the `form action`-tag:

```html
<form action='/test/en' method='POST'>
    <input name='page' type='hidden' value='3'>
    <input name='carried_ec' type='hidden' value='10'>
    <input name='carried_soc' type='hidden' value='9'>
    <input name='populated' type='hidden'>
```

From my point of understanding, they somehow get changed by the java-script functions on the website. But how does this happen, when there is no name-reference to them? My first thought was, maybe there happens something server-side at a PHP-File, but searching for `.php` did not bring a result, so I assume there is no PHP-Magic happening there and it gets done only by the javascript. I wonder and can't find, where the two values get calculated, but maybe this is only due to I am quite new to all this web related stuff.

My final goal is to get each of this questions in an excel sheet and determine, how strong & in which direction each question changes ones political position on the political compass. The reason is, to have some data as foundation for a discussion, if the compass really is a good standard for analysing modern politics, or not.

**What do you suggest me, to do next, to understand, how the javascript calculates those two values?**

[Direct link to the test at the official website](https://www.politicalcompass.org/test/en)

Comment: Just because there's no .php extension doesn't mean there is no server side code. PHP is not the only server side language, and also extension-less URLs are very common.

Comment: "From my point of understanding, they somehow get changed by the the java-script functions on the website"... you could verify this using the Developer Tools to compare the value in the field when the page first loads to the value sent to the server for that field in the next postback. If the values are different you'll know some JavaScript changed it.

Comment: Interesting, did not know, this was possible. Then I will google, how to achieve this with firefox. Thanks for the response. :) @ADyson